# Connect Four; 2D Array confusion

Tags: java, user-interface, multidimensional-array, logic, jlabel

It is my first time working with GUI. I just cant seem to wrap my head around manipulating with it. I feel like the answer is simple (and I am sorry about that), but I just cant get it into my head. :/

I have a 2D JLabel array each set to a default board ImageIcon. I have buttons above each column specifying the column number. In the actionPerformed method, I have this for each button:

```
if(e.getSource()== (whatever column number button name) )
{
}
```

I do not know how to add the token to the lowest row on the specified token, I think that after I find the lowest row set to ImageIcon p0, I will have to set it to pR or pB depending on the player colour. But Im not sure how to write a loop that will do find the lowest cell with p0 stored or how to keep track of the player colour.

```
final ImageIcon p0 = new ImageIcon("Board.jpg");// default board box
final ImageIcon pR = new ImageIcon("Red.jpg");
final ImageIcon pB = new ImageIcon("Black.jpg");

JLabel [][] connectFourBoardComp = new JLabel[6][7];
for(int row=0, count=6; row<1; row++)
{
    for(int col=0; col<7; col++, count++)
    {
          connectFourBoardHumn[row][col].setIcon(p…
          System.out.println(connectFourBoardHumn[…
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep track of the current player's color, just switch the color each time a user plays:

```
if (nextColor == pR) {
    nextColor = pB;
}
else {
    nextColor = pR;
}
```

To find the first row with the p0 icon (assuming the lowest row is at index 0), just loop over the rows until finding the one:

```
int firstEmptyRow = connectFourBoardComp.size(); // default case: the the row is full of tokens
for (int i = 0; i < connectFourBoardComp; i++) {
    if (connectFourBoardComp[i][column] == p0) {
        firstEmptyRow = i;
        break; // break out of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: **Thank you** very much for your reply! Is this what I would write?:                                                  `if(e.getSource()== buttonCompCol0)
        {
   int firstEmptyRow = connectFourBoardComp.size(); // default case: the row is full of tokens
   for (int i = 0; i < connectFourBoardComp; i++) 
   {
       if (connectFourBoardComp[i][0] == p0) 
       {
           firstEmptyRow = i;
           break; // break out of the loop
       }
   }
   
   connectFourBoardComp[i][0].setIcon(nextPlayer);
      
        }`

Comment: No. If you did that, you would compute the first empty row for nothing, since you never use it. The last instruction should be: `if (firstEmptyRow < connectFourBoardComp.size()) { connectFourBoardComp[firstEmptyRow][0].setIcon(nextPlayer); }`. Also, it seems that you'll repeat this code for every column. You shouldn't do that. Instead, put this code into a methog taking the column as argument, use a variable for the column in the action listener, and pass this variable to the method. Also, you should probably display an error message if firstEmptyRow >= connectFourBoardComp.size().

Comment: What would be the problem with repeating the code for every column? If I made a seperate method, is this what I have to do?: In the `actionPerformed` method, for each button, I would set `int column` to the corresponding number and call a method. This method checks and assigns `firstEmptyRow` and places the tokens according to colour. Am I grasping this correctly? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, you're grasping it correctly. The problem is that the longest the code is, the harder it is to maintain it, and the higher the probability is to introduce a bug in it (copy'n pasting and forgetting to change an index, for example). The first rule ofprogramming is DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself. You only have 6 columns here. What would happen if you had 1000? Would you repeat the same code 1000 times? Then why do it if you have 6?

Comment: I understand, I will remember DRY for my future projects :) . Thank you so very much kind sir.